# Substitute for "give or take"

Tags: expressions, synonyms, phrase-requests

Is there a better word or way of saying *give or take* to refer to the possibility of inaccuracy? For example,

> I will be arriving in 30 minutes, give or take 5 minutes.

I want to indicate the possibility of arriving within five minutes of either side. So *about* or *approximately* are too vague.

Comment: Not specify, just indicate there is the possibility that I can arrive 5 minutes either side of in 30 minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a "better" way of saying it.

In a more formal context you might say something more like *"to within five minutes"*, and in a more "geeky" context you might say (or more likely write) *"+/- 5 minutes"*.

But for most purposes (in particular, speech) OP should just stick with *"give or take"*.

Comment: ±5 > +/‒5 > +/- 5

Answer (score 5):

In a technical or scientific context, you can use "with a tolerance of".

For example:

> The process is expected to complete in 30 minutes with a tolerance of
>   5 minutes.

Comment: The scientific merits of your answer sound very good, I am however looking for a more commonplace term/expression.

Comment: Using Bruno's suggestion in everyday conversation might get you noticed. "_I'll be there at 4:30, with a tolerance of 5 minutes_." That might be a great way to set a date with someone wearing [this shirt](http://rlv.zcache.com/talk_nerdy_to_me_tshirt-p235190733707120717b7e6t_400.jpg)

Comment: @J.R. It can get worse... How about "I will be arriving in 30+t minutes, where -5 <= t <= 5"?

Comment: @Bruno: That's rather hard to say conversationally, but that's a great way to text it! :^)

Answer (score 4):

"I will be arriving in 30 minutes, Plus or minus 5 minutes".
"I will be arriving in 25 to 35 minutes".
"I will be arriving within 5 minutes of 4:30".
"I'll be there about 4:30".

Answer (score 3):

Or simply: I'll be there between 4:25 and 4:35.

But if you are looking for a commonplace expression, "*give or take*" is it.

Comment: The problem with that is that cultural expectations of allowable slack that still counts as that time vary a great deal.  For example, try that in Switzerland versus in Mexico, or even in Boston versus Los Angeles for that matter.  I can just see somebody adding another 10 or 15 minutes of slack to both sides of that, meaning you actually need to expect them anywhere between 4:10 – 4:50 instead of the originally stated 4:25 – 4:35.   Perhaps best to say 4:30, and to call if you’re going to miss that by more than a minute or three.  Or five.  See the problem?